# Insert a dot after n character in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have following table in postgres

```
col1 
A018
B672
```

I would like to add a dot first two character. The expected output is:

```
col1   col2
A018   A01.8
B672   B67.2
```

I have tried below query so far

```
with missed_codes as (
SELECT col1, regexp_replace(col1, '(.{2})(?!$)', '\1.') as col2 FROM table 
)
select * from missed_codes ;
```

I am getting this output

```
col1   col2
A018   1.18
B672   1.72
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe just `^(.{3})` would do?

Comment: If they're always 4-char strings, it looks easier to use substrings. If they aren't, we'd need to fine-tune the rules for that case (in fact they're already contradictory because you say dot after first two chars but examples show dot after first three chars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sample data, you don't need regex, just `left` and `substr`:

```sql
with missed_codes as (
  SELECT col1, substr(col1, 1, 3) || '.' || substr(col1, 4) as col2 FROM "table"
)
select * from missed_codes
```

Output:

```
col1    col2
A018    A01.8
B672    B67.2
```

Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/dkqsQ6at)

Comment: Thanks so much.. I get an error using this: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:12 missing EOF at ',' near 'col1'. Any pointers to solve that

Comment: @rshar I don't know how you can get that; if you look at the fiddle you can see the code working fine.

Comment: @rshar you should have mentioned you were using hive, it's a simple change to the query, which I wrote for postgresql as the question asks. Also you should have said you had other data values in a different format, and I could have adjusted the answer to suit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to add a dot after first two digits, In this case you need to use `regexp_replace` :

```
SELECT col1, regexp_replace(col1, '^(\D*\d{2})(?!$)', '\1.') as col2 
FROM "table"
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DtrTSPQx)